# Value assigned to array element comes out as zero

Tags: python, arrays, subtraction

Question: Why does a list element to which I assign a non-zero value become zero?

Have a list called `eta`, which contains a lot of different values. With this list want to make a new list `a`, in which each element `a[i]`, is equal to `eta[i+1]-eta[i]`. The value for `eta[i+1]-eta[i]` can be calculated and can check that it gives me a non-zero value, but when I make a for loop and run it `for i` in some range, it sets `a[i] = 0` for some reason.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(5)
for i in range(5):
    a[i] = eta[i+1]-eta[i]
```

Tried printing the values for `eta[i+1]-eta[i]` for each step and it comes out as a non-zero number, but if print `a[i]` it comes out as zero. [Screenshot of code with prints](https://prnt.sc/l847ov).

Comment: `print(a.dtype)` will show you what's going wrong - you've implicitly created an integer array, and are trying to store tiny floating-point values in it.  Zero *is* the correct answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the data type when calling np.arange() or else it will infer that the indexes should be ints as the parameter passed in is 5 (an int).

Something like this will work.

```
a = np.arange(5, dtype='float')
```

Read more about dtypes here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy.dtype

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that `arange` creates an array of integers, so when you try to assign floating point values to it, truncates it to an integer. Since your values are all between 0 and 1, they are turned into zeroes.